# Invalid file exception on trying to read file with mutagen

Tags: django

I'm trying to get the length of a mp3 file in my view:

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
def Upload(request):
    data = {}
    data['modal'] = render_to_string('partials/modals/upload.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.FILES

        ...

        mp3 = files.get('track')

        mp3 = MP3(mp3);
        print(mp3.info.length);
```

I have checked that the file is not corrupt or invalid, yet when I try to do those last lines of code I get:

> ```
> TypeError: invalid file: <TemporaryUploadedFile: mySong.mp3 (audio/mpeg)>
> ```

I don't understand why it gives me that, because I can read the file and I can even tell django to send the file to my model, and it saves to disk. Why does this not work?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the fix, but I suggest using a form to capture `request.FILES` instead of saving it manually like `mp3 = MP3(mp3)`.

Comment: @ShangWang My web app heavily relies on ajax requests, and using a form in this case is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are meant to instantiate the [`MP3`](http://mutagen.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mp3.html#mutagen.mp3.MP3) class with a filename, not the file handle. I can't see an alternative way to instantiate it with the file handle, so I think you'll have to save the content from `request.FILES` to a file, then do `MP3(filename)`.